# Search DB through MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysql

I have one simple question which I can't understand why it doesn't work. I'm trying to querying the DB through MySQLi and if I hard code a variable works perfect, if I try to make dynamic (via an input box) displays nothing.

Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $searchByInput = $_GET['search'];
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE vin="$searchByInput"';

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //display the table
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm 'echo'ing the variable inside the if statement, displays the right value but for some reason doesn't want to execute the query correctly with this variable.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: Psssst. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php and for future reference http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use single quoted strings inside the query to make it valid, and you should (conveniently) use double quote to expand variables inside the string in the first place:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE vin='$searchByInput'";
```

Even better, let MySQL handle this itself by [binding a parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). This also solves the SQL injection vulnerabilities that were mentioned in the comments:

```
$searchByInput = '';
if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $searchByInput = $_GET['search'];
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE vin=?';

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $searchByInput);

    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //display the table
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've tried that and ended up with an error "2031". Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Done, finally it worked. I think there was a syntax error. You're a star. Thank you so much

Comment: One question, though. Although it's working fine now, whenever I try to run "if(!$stmt->execute()) {
  echo 'Execute failed: (' . $stmt->errno . ') ' . $stmt->error;
 }" it gives the error I've mentioned above. Is there any reason for this at all? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable to:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE vin='$searchByInput'";
```

I think it's a problem with string quotes format. Simple quote format doesn't expand variables.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Tried that already but still no luck. Nothing changed